# how to use pivot_longer in R?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  species = c("species1", "species2", "species3", "species4", "species5", "species6"),
  Position = c("o", "c", "o", "c", "o", "c"),
  MeanPd = c(1.2, 2.5, 3.8, 4.1, 2.3, 1.9),
  sdPd = c(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.6, 0.4, 0.8),
  MeanMd = c(10.2, 9.5, 11.1, 12.4, 10.9, 11.8),
  sdMd = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.2, 0.9, 1.4)
)


df
```

Now I would like to convert this data frame using pivot_longer into a data frame that has the columns called: "species", "Position", "mean", "sd". The column "mean" should contain the mean, either the value from the column meanPd oder MeanMd in the original data frame, and the column sd should contain the corresponding standard deviation from the original data frame (either sdPd or sdMd). I know it is possible to do this with pivot_longer but I do not know the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

When you want to simultaneously put multiple variables in long format, like here, you should use a combination of `names_to` and `names_pattern`. You define the pattern of existing columns in `names_pattern` (here, the first group is either Mean or sd, and the second group is Pd or Md). In `names_to`, where you define new column names, `.value` refers to:

> ".value" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name
> defines the name of the output column containing the cell values,
> overriding values_to entirely.

Here, it'll create the Mean and sd columns.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(species, Position), names_pattern = "(Mean|sd)(.*)",
               names_to = c(".value", "variable"))

# # A tibble: 12 × 5
#    species  Position variable  Mean    sd
#    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 species1 o        Pd         1.2   0.5
#  2 species1 o        Md        10.2   1.1
#  3 species2 c        Pd         2.5   0.7
#  4 species2 c        Md         9.5   1.3
#  5 species3 o        Pd         3.8   0.9
#  6 species3 o        Md        11.1   1.6
#  7 species4 c        Pd         4.1   0.6
#  8 species4 c        Md        12.4   1.2
#  9 species5 o        Pd         2.3   0.4
# 10 species5 o        Md        10.9   0.9
# 11 species6 c        Pd         1.9   0.8
# 12 species6 c        Md        11.8   1.4
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that seems to be working. What I forgot is that I need an additional column in the end which is called "variable". This column should contain either pd or md to know which mean/sd it is. How can I do this?

Comment: Check edit, you have to include a new group

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, we can convert @Maël answer back to the OP's input with `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(species, Position), names_pattern = "(Mean|sd)(.*)",
               names_to = c(".value", "variable")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(variable),
              values_from=c(Mean,sd),
              names_sep ="")

# A tibble: 6 × 6
  species  Position MeanPd MeanMd  sdPd  sdMd
  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 species1 o           1.2   10.2   0.5   1.1
2 species2 c           2.5    9.5   0.7   1.3
3 species3 o           3.8   11.1   0.9   1.6
4 species4 c           4.1   12.4   0.6   1.2
5 species5 o           2.3   10.9   0.4   0.9
6 species6 c           1.9   11.8   0.8   1.4
```