# Tidy Pivot a Table based on 3 columns in R

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

Current data:

```
user_ID age_v1 age_v2 age_v3 gender visit score

1         63      65     67     M     v1     8 
1         63      65     67     M     v2     4 
1         63      65     67     M     v3     1
```

I would like a tidyverse solution to create an age column with values corresponding to the specific visit. Desired output, something like:

```
user_ID age gender visit score

1        63   M      v1    8 
1        65   M      v2    4 
1        67   M      v3    1
```

Note: other similar solutions (like this one: [how to use pivot_longer in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76280929/how-to-use-pivot-longer-in-r)) result in an exploded dataset in my case creating many duplicate rows. See response to initial answer (which does the same thing).

Comment: The following will work: `mydf |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("age"), values_to = "age") |> 
  separate_wider_delim(name, delim = "_", names = c(NA, "visit_2")) |> 
  filter(visit == visit_2) |> 
  select(user_ID, age, gender, visit, score)`

Comment: Yes! Excellent. Thanks so much @Phil. This was a good solution. Not sure why they closed the issue as duplicate when it wasn't. But I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("age"), names_to = "x", values_to = "age") %>% 
  select(-x) %>% 
  relocate(age, .after = user_ID)

  user_ID   age gender visit score
    <int> <int> <chr>  <chr> <int>
1       1    63 M      v1        8
2       1    65 M      v1        8
3       1    67 M      v1        8
4       1    63 M      v2        4
5       1    65 M      v2        4
6       1    67 M      v2        4
7       1    63 M      v3        1
8       1    65 M      v3        1
9       1    67 M      v3        1
```

Comment: Thanks @Jilber Urbina. This is close. But notice how the visits get duplicated. There should be one row per visit, with the corresponding age. So the output should be 3 rows (see desired output above in the question): age in v1 = 63, age in v2 = 65, and age in v3 = 67, with all other columns for this case (ID = 1) staying the same for corresponding visits as with age

Comment: Follow up: @Phil's answer above in the comments was correct.